# How do I use service workers with an htaccess protected directory?

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, service-worker, http-status-code-401

I'm trying some basic service workers. The service worker itself will work normally the first time the service worker is registered. The problem I always get is once the person revisits the website in the future (e.g. the following day) and tries to access a `.htaccess`/`.htpasswd` protected directory. Instead of getting the dialog box, as normal, they go straight to a 401 error.

This is how I am registering the service worker in script tags in the HTML.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```

I have tried a couple of different methods in the `sw.js` itself and every time I get the same error. This is one from the Google airhorner example, I believe...

```
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  const timeStamp = Date.now();
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open('somename').then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll([
        `/`,
        `/index.html`,
        `/css/tour-2.css`
      ])
          .then(() => self.skipWaiting());
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
      event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request, {ignoreSearch: true}).then(response => {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to use service workers with websites with `.htaccess` protected directories?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to cure is:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    // Exclude admin panel.
    if (0 === event.request.url.indexOf("https://www.my-site.com/my-protected-area")) {
        return;
    }
```

It should help.

[Source: TIV.NET](https://www.tiv.net/2018/07/service-worker-and-401-authorization.html)